# Distributed software for calculating $\pi$ or $e$

Tags: math-software, pi

Is there a "SETI at Home" style initiative for calculating constants with distributed computing?

Answer (score 1):

There was [PiHex](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/pihex/index.html) which has now ended. I am not aware of any others - someone may correct me